# htaccess external rewrite / internal redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are two things that I would like to achieve with .htaccess file.
The first one is

```
www.hostname.com/index.php?question  -> www.hostname.com/question
www.hostname.com/index.php?myinfo  -> www.hostname.com/myinfo
www.hostname.com/index.php?notification  -> www.hostname.com/notification
```

so I use external rewrite to re-express on the URL as following.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(index.php)\?([^&]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L]
```

Now the above statement correctly displays as I want. The problem is to internally convert back when a condition is satisfied. The condition is if `%{THE_REQUEST}` is equal to any character after '`/`'.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

So that my php code can recognize the `$_GET` parameter. Here, even though the condition is satisfied it will not process the RewriteRule.

The second problem is

```
www.hostname.com/index.php?category=spo  -> www.hostname.com/category/spo
www.hostname.com/index.php?category=ite  -> www.hostname.com/category/ite
www.hostname.com/index.php?category=gam  -> www.hostname.com/category/gam
```

The conversion is completed using exteral rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(index)\?category=([^&]+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ category/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Again, I'd like to convert back whatever is written in the URL back to the original format internally so I use the following condition to differentiate from the previous case,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

my php code cannot recognize the `$_GET` parameter and variable. When I use htacces tester, it says it should work but it doesn't. http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

How do I fix this problem? OR is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Appears to be fine. What does your PHP code look like?

Comment: The %{REQUEST_URI} is not required in both cases and the dot in the check on %{THE_REQUEST} should be escaped. That said, the rules should work. You either have other rules working on the rewritten url, or your php code doesn't actually check the $_GET variable, but processes the request differently instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?category=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The first line, `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index)\?category=([^&]+) [NC]` gives me 500 internal error.

Comment: Sorry had a typo, fixed it. Can you try now?

Comment: These are the links I receive now. The page does not display correctly either. `http://www.hostname.com/myquestions%20HTTP/1.1`, `http://www.hostname.com/category/pol%20HTTP/1.1`

Comment: I fixed it by changing i to:. `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?category=([^&]+)\ HTTP [NC]` so both case displays fine on the URL bar as I wanted. it displays as `www.hostname.com/something`, and works fine internally. however, `www.hostname.com/category/something does not work correctly.

Comment: `http://www.hostname.com/category/spo` displays something but it does not display correctly

Comment: I had another mistake, corrected it now. Please try again.

Comment: `/category/something` should be loading `/index.php?category=something`.

Comment: okay so what happens how is ... if i click on a link that says `index.php?category=rel` then it shows as `/category/rel` which is what I wanted. But the page does not display correctly. If i type in `/category=rel` as the url it displays correctly because of the second group of statements. do you think there are conflicts somewhere between two statements? should I add some RewriteCond??

Comment: Thank you so much, by the way, for your help.

Comment: Actually `/category/rel` is also being rewritten to `/index.php?category=rel`. You write `page does not display correctly` that means your css/js/images aren't being displayed correctly. Which is due to use of relative URLs on css/js etc. With the use `/category/rel` it might be trying to fetch css/js from `/category` path now. To avoid this problem use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/` OR else You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: You are awesome. `<base href="/" />` works perfectly. Thank you so much.