# htaccess rewrite rules same domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url rewrite issue on the .htaccess file. There are 2 rules on the file:

rule 1 // When user open "example.com/test.php" on a browser then user will be redirected to "example.com/test".

```
htaccess rule: RewriteRule ^test.php(.*)$ http://example.com/test/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

rule 2 // When user will open "example.com/test" we will retrieve the content from "example.com/test.php".

```
htaccess rule: RewriteRule ^test/ test.php [NC]
```

Right now those rules are not working, maybe there is a conflict somewhere.
What rewrite rules i should use for the above conditions?

Comment: Most likely [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210606/htaccess-external-rewrite-internal-redirect) will answer your question. I can't tell from the description "rules are not working" if you just forgot to activate mod_rewrite, or that you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two rules conflict with one an other. One writes test.php to test and the other writes test to test.php, which is likely to leave you in an infinite loop, either within the rewrite engine or between the browser and server depending on how you implement the rewrite.

To solve this I've used a condition to check the requested URI rather than the URI as its currently rewritten.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ test.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (/[^\ ]*)\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule ^test\.php(.*)$ http://example.com/test/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Couple of things to note that might also be factors:

1. You hadn't escaped the dot in `test.php` in your first rewrite
2. The Apache [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) directive can get in the way and do some rewriting before you get your hands on the on the URI in .htaccess. If you have file test.php, but a request is just made to http://example.com/test, then your htaccess will be working with test.php, not just test as you might expect.
3. Browsers cache redirects which can make it difficult to diagnose problems